# Check if a utility function represents a monotone preference

Tags: microeconomics, expected-utility

Given a function $u(x_1, x_2) = x_1 +x_2 + \min(2x_1, x_2)$, how do we mathematically prove that it monotonic or not?

Is there is a general algebraic technique to show monotonicity of suchlike functions?

Comment: For problems like this, you always start with a definition. What's the definition of a monotonic transformation?

Comment: @Art I don't think monotonic transformation is what you meant. There is no need to transform anything.

Comment: @Giskard Oops my bad. [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_preferences) is the definition I meant. The question implies that the function $u(x_1, x_2)$ could be said to be monotonic or not. My understanding is that a "monotonic function" applies to $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ only. So I guess what I'm suggesting is to change title to "Check if a utility function represents a monotone preference."

Answer (score 1):

Using [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_preferences) definition of monotone preferences (Thanks to User [Art](https://economics.stackexchange.com/users/5145/art)). Let $X\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ be the set of possible consumption bundles, and $x,y\in X$. We have weak monotone preferences if $y>>x \implies y\succ x $, and strict preferences if $y\geq x \implies y\succ x$. If we have a utility function $u: X\to \mathbb{R}$, then $y\succ x$ is the same as $u(y)> u(x)$.

Regarding notation for two bundles $x,y\in X, x=(x_1,x_2,...,x_n), y=(y_1,y_2,...,y_n)$, we say $y>>x$ if $y_i>x_i$ forall $i=1,2,...,n$ and we say $y\geq x$ if $y_i\geq x_i$ forall $i=1,2,...,n$ and there is a $j$, such that $y_j>x_j$. (This notation is not universal)

Now, see if you can use this to answer your question